# Advance pivot with duplicate entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two tables.
The first one is a simple lookup table with two columns. *name* and *short_name*.

- **name** is for example Arthur.
- **short_name** is simply a.

The other table has the columns: *title*, *year*, *area*, *pre*, *current*, *post*.

- **title** refers to the area name for example 'Lot 1'.
- **year** is simple the year. For example 2023, 2024 etc.
- **area** is a measurement of the area for example 4,5,6 etc.
- **pre** contains a single name for example a (meaning Arthur)
- **current** is the same as pre, but a different name
- **post** is the same as pre but with a different name.

The first table:

[image: the first table]

The second table:

[image: the second table]

I tried creating a pivot table with both tables. But I can't get it to work so that the pivot has years as the primary Columns and the pre, current and post as secondary Columns. The Rows should be the names, with values being the sum of the area of the given names.

How it should look like:

[image: how it should look like]

The first problem I encountered is that I can't map the relationship between the two tables, multiple times. So pre, current and post to the name of the first table. And also using the area values for pre current and post.

Comment: Your second table is not "PivotTable-ready". You need a single column for "Type" which contains "pre", "current" and "post" as rows. You can easily convert the table you have into the right format using PowerQuery, where you could also do a "merge" to join to the people table via the short names, then return the data as a single table that is PT-ready, or probably directly output in Pivotted format (I have not worked through the detail of the last option in my head yet)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did in the end. But the problem is that there is a lot more duplication now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting the table so pre, current and post are rows in one column of the table and a new column called type has been added. After that, I moved the area to a new table, so there is a bit less duplication. And then I made a pivot table with relationships with the given tables. Works but it's combersome

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).